# I am getting an error when I try to run my code. local port 127.0.0.1:3310 cannot be bound

Tags: mysql, database

```
Success: SSH tunnel open - you are connecting to knuth.gcd.ieon port 22 with username s3025673
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:3310 cannot be bound.
    at jsch@0.1.54/com.jcraft.jsch.PortWatcher.<init>(PortWatcher.java:158).
```

It was working beofore.

Comment: *What* code are you running? ^^ Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Sorry this is it. I am having a issue with the ports
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Starting");
  String mysqlUsername = 
  String mysqlPassword = 
  String mysqlDatabaseName = 
  String sshUsername = 
  String sshPassword = 
  String sshRemoteHost = 
  int shhRemotePort = 22;
  int localPort = 3310;
  String mysqlHost="localhost";
  int remoteMySQLPort = 3306;

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the code rather than writing the code in a comment. If you have not already done so, then consider taking the [tour].